# Saving a TransformedBitmap Object to disk.

Tags: c#, wpf, image, bitmap, save

Working in WPF and C#, I have a TransformedBitmap object that I either:

1. Need to save to disk as a bitmap type of file (ideally, I'll allow users to choose whether it's saved as a BMP, JPG, TIF, etc, though, I'm not to that stage yet...)
2. Need to convert to a BitmapImage object as I know how to get a byte[] from a BitmapImage object.

Unfortunately, at this point I'm really struggling to get either one of those two things done.

Can anyone offer any help or point out any methods I might be missing?

Comment: Posting a link isnt really an answer, but i thought this might be a good start. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750864.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All of your encoders are using `BitmapFrame` class for creating frames that will be added to `Frames` collection property of encoder. `BitmapFrame.Create` method has variety of overloads and one of them accepts parameter of `BitmapSource` type. So as we know that `TransformedBitmap` inherits from `BitmapSource` we can pass it as a parameter to `BitmapFrame.Create` method. Here are the methods which works as you have described:

```
public bool WriteTransformedBitmapToFile<T>(BitmapSource bitmapSource, string fileName) where T : BitmapEncoder, new()
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName) || bitmapSource == null)
                return false;

            //creating frame and putting it to Frames collection of selected encoder
            var frame = BitmapFrame.Create(bitmapSource);
            var encoder = new T();
            encoder.Frames.Add(frame);
            try
            {
                using (var fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    encoder.Save(fs);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        private BitmapImage GetBitmapImage<T>(BitmapSource bitmapSource) where T : BitmapEncoder, new()
        {
            var frame = BitmapFrame.Create(bitmapSource);
            var encoder = new T();
            encoder.Frames.Add(frame);
            var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
            bool isCreated;
            try
            {
                using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    encoder.Save(ms);
                    ms.Position = 0;

                    bitmapImage.BeginInit();
                    bitmapImage.StreamSource = ms;
                    bitmapImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                    bitmapImage.EndInit();
                    isCreated = true;
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                isCreated = false;
            }
            return isCreated ? bitmapImage : null;
        }
```

They accept any BitmapSource as the first parameter and any BitmapEncoder as a generic type parameter.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Wow, very much so!  I didn't really know how the different encoders worked (or how to apply them). Thanks a ton!

Comment: As a note, although OP claims to "*need to convert to a BitmapImage object as I know how to get a byte[] from a BitmapImage object*", the conversion is entirely redundant. When you create a BitmapFrame from a BitmapSource and encode that to a MemoryStream you do already have the byte array wrapped by the MemoryStream. No need to create another BitmapImage.

Comment: However, if you create a BitmapImage from a stream the is closed right after EndInit(), you need to set its CacheOption property to `BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad`. Some decoders (like JPEG) also require that the stream's Position is reset to zero after encoding.